# How to chain expressions inside ngClass when using the {...}[] form

Tags: angularjs

How can I add another expression to an `ng-class` directive that uses this form:

```
ng-class="{true:'loading', false:'loading-done'}[data.loader===null]"
```

I'd like to add something like this to the list:

```
{highlight:isSpecial}
```

Is it possible without expanding the first expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently using `ngClass` ([see the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)) with "*a string representing space delimited class names*". To add another class, separate it from the other with a space:

```
<div ng-class="{true:'loading', false:'loading-done'}[data.loader===null] + (isSpecial ? ' highlight' : '')" />
```

But why are you using such an ugly form? A more readable solution is simply to use "*a map of class names to boolean values*":

```
<div ng-class="{loading: data.loader === null, loading-done: data.loader !== null, highlight: isSpecial}" />
```

Comment: I was thinking that the "uglier" form doesn't evaluate `data.loader===null` 2 times.

Comment: @Francisc That's right. But that is a simple comparison of primitives, which has no impact on performance.

Comment: Yeah, but next it might not be a primitive. Thank you.